# Find dynamic style attribute in a webelement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm having a problem extracting the full style Attribute, as part of it still didn't reached the DOM- Its an image that sometimes takes 1-2 seconds to load in the screen, so what happens is that there IS a string with attribute, but it CHANGES when the image arrives from the server.
I'm doing a WebDriverWait for the element to be visible in the DOM, but when I try to take its "style" attribute (that has the "...;(url:"http://....")", it sometimes isn't there, and then my substring() fails.

Here is the code:

```
@Step("Print Image src url")
public String printImage(Integer imgNo){ 
    WebElement imgStyle = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 15)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(Consts.ACTIVE_IMG_XPATH_1000 + "/div[" + (currentImg + 1) +"]/div[1]"))); 
    String styleString = imgStyle.getAttribute("style");
    Integer idxUrl = styleString.indexOf("url");
    Integer idxJpg = styleString.indexOf("jpg");
    String urlImage = styleString.substring(idxUrl+5,idxJpg+3); //styleString.indexOf("http"),20
    Log.info("V - Image " + imgNo + " src is: " + urlImage);
    return urlImage;
}
```

I can simply add System.wait(3000), but I don't wan't to use it. Any ideas how to solve it nicer? Can I wait for visibility of String?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

What is the HTML like? You could use `contains` or `starts-with` and the beginning of the url before the part that is dynamic and changes. Like `WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@style, 'text']"))`

Comment: This is the HTML of the element in the first few seconds:  `<div class="cbola-box-item-image" style="overflow: hidden; width: 502.5px; height: 251.25px;">` and this is the div after 2-3 seconds after the JPG arrives: `<div class="cbola-box-item-image" style="overflow: hidden; width: 502.5px; height: 251.25px; background: url("http://media.carambo.la/Images/4630_3_6.jpg") center center / cover no-repeat;">`